# What is the difference between SUA and SAA?

Tags: terminology, airspace, special-use-airspace

I would like to understand the difference between Special Use Airspace (SUA) and Special Activity Airspace (SAA). I found the following definitions.

[Eurocontrol Lexicon](https://ext.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/index.php/Special_Use_Airspace) for SUA (from FAA):

> Airspace of defined dimensions identified by an area on the surface of
>   the earth wherein activities must be confined because of their nature
>   and/or wherein limitations may be imposed upon aircraft operations
>   that are not a part of those activities.

[Eurocontrol Lexicon](https://ext.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/index.php/Special_Activity_Airspace) for SAA (from FAA):

> [U.S.] Any airspace with defined dimensions within the National
>   Airspace System wherein limitations may be imposed upon aircraft
>   operations. This airspace may be restricted areas, prohibited areas,
>   military operations areas, air ATC assigned airspace, and any other
>   designated airspace areas.

Can you please help me to understand what the difference is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAA is a project being undertaken to **unify** how SUA's (and [ATCAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_use_airspace)'s) are defined, managed, and shared.

> - [SAA will] define SUAs and ATCAAs in a consistent manner using an editing tool
> - Use a Service Oriented Architecture (SOA) to distribute that data to interested users
> - Manage the schedule and status of those airspaces through a SOA.

SAA is part of the [System Wide Information Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Wide_Information_Management) (SWIM).

In short, SAA encompasses SUA, ATCAA, etc.

---

<sup>Source: [SAA Modernization](https://www.faa.gov/nextgen/programs/swim/documentation/media/demo_tim_5/8_DemosTIM5_AIM.ppt) (.ppt file)</sup>

Comment: SUA is defined by Title [14 CFR Part 73](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=5f4a825f043153b07a3dd8844913cc0a&mc=true&node=pt14.2.73&rgn=div5)

Comment: defined as in regulatory definition of what constitutes special use airspace.

Comment: Reading thru the presentation I see where the discussion is about how to define a specific SUA (part of the management initiative).  14 CFR is the legal definition - which is interesting in that it only describes restricted and prohibited airspace.

Comment: @Gerry: From the [AIM](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap3_section_4.html): *Warning areas, MOAs, alert areas, CFAs, and national security areas (NSA) are **nonregulatory** special use airspace.* / Off coast warning areas also exceed the territorial waters, which is I *guess* why they're not defined via regulatory means.

Comment: That explains it. I did know about Warning areas from my USAF days. They're in international airspace so there's no legal authority over them. They were defined for two reasons; 1. To allow for scheduling management of the areas, and 2. For use in NOTAMs so that everyone else could know when to stay clear.